# (psycopg2.OperationalError) SSL SYSCALL error: Software caused connection abort

Tags: python, apache, flask, amazon-redshift

I am using apache with mod_wsgi in windows platform to deploy my flask application. I am using sqlalchemy to connect redshift database with connection pool(size 10).
After few days suddenly I am getting follwoing error.
(psycopg2.OperationalError) SSL SYSCALL error: Software caused connection abort

Can anybody suggest why I am getting this error and how to fix?

If I do the apache restart then this error gone. But after few days it again comeback.

Comment: SSL SYSCALL indicates that the Redshift connection has dropped. This can either be on your client side, or on the AWS side (maintenance windows, cluster reboots, WorkLoad Managment). I would check first on the AWS Redshift console for the maintenance window setting and the query timeout setting, this latter is in the WLM. If not, check on your client, some clients have timeout settings for open connections, or you might have some  connectivity problems.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this error by turning `DEBUG=False` in my config file [and/or in the run.py]. Hope it helps someone.